# Laravel Query Sorting with 2 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to sort 2 tables in Laravel. I have a Thread-Table and an Answer-Table for the Threads.
So I would like to sort by the last answer -> thread creation date.

Here is my code:

```
$last_posts = DB::table('threads')
                ->join('threads__answers', 'threads__answers.thread', '=', 'threads.id')
                ->orderBy('threads__answers.id', 'DESC')
                ->orderBy('threads.id', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```

My problem is... if the thread has multiple answers, the topic is displayed multiple times in the foreach. I want the thread to be sorted by topicality including the answers (display once). I hope you understand my problem/question. I am desperate and hope you can help me.

I use the foreach for a basic bootstrap-table.

Comment: I have model "Thread" and Model "Thread_Answers". And I want to sort by the last answers (if exists) and the thread creation date. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$last_posts = DB::table('threads')
            ->join('threads__answers', 'threads__answers.thread', '=', 'threads.id')
            ->orderBy('threads__answers.id', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't work like I thought it would. There must be a solution to list the threads once instead of how many answers exist. But thank you for your help. :)